# Moq Setup To Exercise Generic Type Call Return of String

Tags: c#, moq

How can one Mock this interface, to not get an null reference exception when explicitly typing a `string` for the `Setup`?

### Interface

```
public interface IUtil
{
    T GetSetting<T>(string key);
}
```

#### Code

```
var mock = new Mock<IUtil>();
mock.Setup(mk => mk.GetSetting<string>("Jabberwocky")).Returns("Valid");

var uMock = mock as IUtil;

string mySetting = uMock.GetSetting<string>("Jabberwocky"); // GetSetting Returns Null Reference
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The exception was occurring because I was attempting to cast the mock instance to the interface; which does not work. I should have been casting the `.Object` property such as

```
IUtil uMock = mock.Object;
```

Comment: The `as` is not needed at all...this isn't a good answer now

Comment: Fixed from `as` to definition. .

Comment: I still says casting ;) (there isn't a cast in the code)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `It.AnyType` during the Setup phase:

```
const string expectedInput = "Jabberwocky";
const string expectedOutput = "Valid";

var mock = new Mock<IUtil>();
mock
   .Setup(mk => mk.GetSetting<It.IsAnyType>()>(expectedInput))
   .Returns(expectedOutput);
```